# Keras Tensoflow full reset

Tags: loops, tensorflow, keras, model, reset

I know that this question was asked many times by many people but I still don't have any working solution.

I have a Python code that tends to create a model, fit it and then predict something. Since I have many features to train the model with I've created a list of all combinations of my features like 2 of 10, 4 of 10 etc. Now I wanted to call my code in a loop.

```
The loop looks like:

for each combination in all combinations:
    model = Sequential()
    ... add some layers...
    model.compile(...)
    model.fit()
    ...
    model.predict()
```

And I see that every time I run it on the same set of features I got different results. Of course I've disabled all the randomness so it is not an issue. If I just run my code from command line (without the loop - i.e. the python fully exits between the runs) I get a fully repeating result.

So my assumption was that either Keras or/and Tensorflow do not reset cleanly between the loops.

I've tried many things like putting the following lines after I want my model to be discarded:

```
model.reset_states()
del model
gc.collect()
tf.keras.backend.set_learning_phase(1)
keras.backend.clear_session()
K.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops
ops.reset_default_graph()
```

Nothing works - the results between the loops are inconsistent. The only way to work correctly is to run my file from a batch file with a lot of lines that allow python to exit before running next time.

Any suggestions how to deal with that? I'm on Windows with TS 2.4.1 and latest keras.

Thanks

I'm using this code to prevent randomness:

```
def reset_random_seeds():
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(1)
    tf.random.set_seed(1)
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(1)
```

Comment: `Of course I've disabled all the randomness so it is not an issue.` I'm pretty sure **this is** the issue. Consider reading the [documentation of `tf.random.set_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I've added to the post my code that I use to disable the randomness.

Comment: And if I run my code several times (not in the loop inside the same code) I get the same results. It is just when I run it without exiting Python I get different results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: you need to reset the random generator state in your loop that creates the model, by calling `tf.random.set_seed`.

### Explanation:

A neural network consists of a series of mathematical operations. Most frequently an operation in a neural network can be viewed as the following linear equation : `y=W*x+b`, where:

- `x` is the input
- `y` is the output
- `W` is the weight of the node of the network
- `b` is the bias of the node of the network.

(All those linear equation are then separated by a non linearity to avoid a collapse of the network).

Most of the time, neural networks have their weights (`W`) initialized randomly. Which means that every time that you run the training of a neural network, you will get a slightly different results. If your model is robust enough, those results will be statistically similar.

Now, if one wants to be able to reproduce some exact results, that random initialization of weights can be a problem. To be able to reproduce some exact numbers, one can set a seed to the random generator, that provides the guarantee that during the execution of the program, the generated random numbers will always be from the same series, in the same order.

#### Running the same program twice in the terminal

Consider the following program, named `network_with_seed.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,input_shape=(1,))])
print(model.trainable_weights)
```

That program is a simple network with one fully connected layer with node(also known as a perceptron). That network as one weight `W`, that the program will print.

If we execute that program a first time, we get:

```
$ python network_with_seed.py
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.7206192]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

Now, If we execute that code again:

```
python network_with_seed.py
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.7206192]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

We get exactly the same value for the weight `W`, `-0.7206192`, thanks to the seed.

#### Creating a model in a loop

Now, lets imagine that we want to create that network twice, and get some numbers, but we want to do everything in one python script.

Consider that program, `loop_network_with_seed.py`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.random.set_seed(0)
for idx in range(2):
  print(f"Model {idx+1}")
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,input_shape=(1,))])
  print(model.trainable_weights)
```

If we run it

```
$ python loop_network_with_seed.py
Model 1
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.7206192]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
Model 2
[<tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.19195998]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

If we just look at the randomly initialized kernel `W` we see, for the same model, different values : `-0.7206192, 0.19195998`, and not the same one as when we were executing the same model twice in a row by calling our script `network_with_seed.py`. If we train those two networks, we won't get exactly the same results, because their initial weight `W` is different.

Note that if you were to run that program again, you will get exactly the same results, because the weight of the model 1 will be set to `-0.7206192` again, and the weight `W` of the model 2 will be set to  `0.19195998`, thanks to the seed. The seed makes the randomness reproducible between each run.

This is because of the internal state of the random number generator. For more information, you can read the [documentation of `tf.random.set_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/set_seed)

#### Resetting the random generator state

If you want reproducible results for the same set of parameters, you need to reset the random state before the creation of each model. By setting the seed back, we ensure that the same random values will be used for our weights `W`.

Consider the final program `network_with_seed_in_loop.py`

```
import tensorflow as tf

for _ in range(2):
  print(f"Model {idx+1}")
  tf.random.set_seed(0)
  model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1,input_shape=(1,))])
  print(model.trainable_weights)
```

Outputs :

```
$ python network_with_seed_in_loop.py`
Model 1
[<tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.7206192]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
Model 2
[<tf.Variable 'dense_1/kernel:0' shape=(1, 1) dtype=float32, numpy=array([[-0.7206192]], dtype=float32)>, <tf.Variable 'dense_1/bias:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.], dtype=float32)>]
```

Here, the internal state is reset, and the kernel `W` of each network are equal.

Comment: Actually putting my code that disables randomness solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I was to quick to answer. In fact I'm still wondering what happens in my case. First of all, at the beginning of my code I disable that randomness using this code 'def reset_random_seeds():
    os.environ['PYTHONHASHSEED'] = str(1)
    tf.random.set_seed(1)
    np.random.seed(1)
    random.seed(1)'

Comment: The problem is that I don't get random results on prediction. If that would be the case I would understand. The problem is that if I run my program twice from the command prompt I get EXACTLY same result - let's call it A. But if I run with a loop twice, I get result A and result B that are different. But ALWAYS THE SAME. So it seems like it is somehow not cleaned between the runs. Or another question - do I need to call that set_seed after each model created again? I thought that doing it once when I start the code is sufficient. Is it being reset during the model compile/fit/predict cycle?

Comment: I've added a bit more explanation, tell me if it's still unclear.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a great answer. Now I see that I need to set the same seed each time the model is created. Outstanding answer